# 400 status on login request for asp.net core 2.0

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following issue.

After upgrading an application to ASP.NET 2.0 I get a 400 (bad request) status response whenever trying to authenticate in production.

This error does not reproduce locally and doesn't reproduce when using the production container locally.

The only difference that exists between production and local is that there is a reverse proxy in production that implements SSL for all requests.

I've tried moving the authentication code from middleware (as it was initially implemented) into a controller and I've changed the path to the route that was used for authentication. I still get the error.

All other requests work fine (provided you have a jwt token attached to them).

I should also mention that the CORS headers aren't set on the 400 response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into this as well, I CAN reproduce locally, but it's intermittent.

Comment: I am also running into this issue running an ASP.NET Core 2.2 webserver on a Raspberry Pi behind an nGinX reverse proxy with the following config : I jget a 400 response when hitting the login button.

```location / { 

    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; 

    proxy_http_version 1.1; 

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 

    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 

} ```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by an upstream reverse proxy that was stripping some headers from the requests. Requests with verbs Post & Put were affected.

Set the log level of your application to `Information` to see what Kestrel is actually complaining about.

In our case we had to switch hosting providers because of the issue.